# Why should I implement ICloneable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, cloneable, icloneable

Can you explain to me why I should inherit from `ICloneable` and implement the `Clone()` method?

If I want to do a deep copy, can't I just implement my method? Let's say `MyClone()`?

Why should I inherit from `ICloneable`? What are the advantages? Is it just a matter of making code "more readable"?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You shouldn't. Microsoft recommends against implementing `ICloneable` because there's no clear indication from the interface whether your `Clone` method performs a "deep" or "shallow" clone.

See [this blog post from Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx) back in 2003(!) for more information.

Comment: Wayback link to article, which is 404 now: http://web.archive.org/web/20040419170407/http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx

Comment: A better link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/05/03/should-we-obsolete-icloneable-the-slar-on-system-icloneable/

Answer (score 30):

The `ICloneable` interface *by itself* isn't very useful, which is to say that there really aren't many situations where it's useful to know that an object is cloneable without knowing anything else about it.  This is a very different situation from e.g. `IEnumerable` or `IDisposable`; there are many situations where it's useful to accept an `IEnumerable` without knowing anything other than how to enumerate it.

On the other hand, `ICloneable` may be useful when applied as a generic constraint along with other constraints.  For example, a base class might usefully support a number of derivatives, some of which could be usefully cloned, and some of which could not.  If the base type itself exposed a public cloning interface, then any derivative type which could not be cloned would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle.  The way to avoid this problem is to have the base type support cloning using a Protected method, and allow derived types to implement a public cloning interface as they see fit.

Once that was accomplished, a method which wants to accept an object of a `WonderfulBase` type, and needs to be able to clone it, could be coded to accept a WonderfulBase object which supports cloning (using a generic type parameter with base-type and `ICloneable` constraints).  Although the `ICloneable` interface would not itself indicate deep or shallow cloning, the documentation for `WonderfulBase` would indicate whether cloneable `WonderfulBase` should be deep- or shallow-cloned.  Essentially, the `ICloneable` interface wouldn't accomplish anything that wouldn't be accomplished by defining `ICloneableWonderfulBase`, except that it would avoid having to define different names for every different cloneable base class.

Answer (score 19):

`ICloneable` is one of those artifacts in the BCL which has been controversial. There is no real reason IMHO to implement it. With that said if I am going to create a clone method then I do implement `ICloneable`, and I provide my own strong typed version of `Clone`.

The issue with `ICloneable` is it never indicated if `Clone` was a shallow or a deep copy which are very different things. The fact that there is no `ICloneable<T>` might be an indication on Microsoft's thoughts about ICloneable

Answer (score 10):

Matt is correct, don't use it. Create your own `Copy()` method (or similar name) and make it *perfectly clear* in your public API whether your method is creating a deep or shallow copy of your object.