# C# stack overflow

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, icloneable

I am trying to find out why I am getting a stack overflow exception. I am creating a simple card game for a school assignment and when I clone the cards to return them I get the stack overflow exception.

So I got this card class:

```
public class Card : ICloneable
{
    ....

    #region ICloneable Members

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone(); // <--- here is the error thrown when the first card is to be cloned
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and I have a class called `Hand` which then clones the cards:

```
internal class Hand
{
        internal List<Card> GetCards()
        {
            return m_Cards.CloneList<Card>(); // m_Cards is a List with card objects
        }
}
```

Last, I got an extension method for the `List`:

```
    public static List<T> CloneList<T>(this List<T> listToClone) where T : ICloneable
    {
        return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
    }
```

The error gets thrown in the card class (IClonable method),

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in CardLibrary.dll

Comment: Do the cards need to be mutable i.e. do they have state that can change? If not then you could just have a set of immutable cards that you could reuse in different collections. No cloneing needed.

Comment: Please see also this discussion regarding ICloneable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c

Comment: After reading the title of this question I was thinking this belongs on meta... ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're calling yourself:

```
public object Clone()
{
    return this.Clone();
}
```

This results in infinite recursion.

Your Clone() method should copy all properties/fields to a new object:

```
public object Clone()
{
    Card newCard = new Card();

    newCard.X = this.X;
    // ...

    return newCard;
}
```

or you could use MemberwiseClone()

```
public object Clone()
{
    return MemberwiseClone();
}
```

But that gives you less control over the cloning process.

Comment: +1, great answer. Whenever using `MemberwiseClone()` just don't forget that it only creates a shallow copy, i.e. if a class field is a reference type, the reference is copied, but not the referenced object.

Answer (score 0):

I've tended to use MemberwiseClone() for the simple data, and then implemented ICloneable throghout the hierarchy of elements that I've needed to clone, so:

```
public class CRMLazyLoadPrefs : ICloneable
{
    public bool Core { get; set; }
    public bool Events { get; set; }    
    public bool SubCategories { get; set; }
    public OrganisationLazyLoadPrefs { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        CRMLazyLoadPrefs _prefs = new CRMLazyLoadPrefs();
        // firstly, shallow copy the booleans
        _prefs  = (CRMLazyLoadPrefs)this.MemberwiseClone();
        // then deep copy the other bits
        _prefs.Organisation = (OrganisationLazyLoadPrefs)this.Organisation.Clone();
    }
}
```

Where OrganisationLazyLoadPrefs also implements ICloneable and so on and so forth throughout the hierarchy.

Hope this helps,
Cheers,
Terry

Comment: just seen that comment from @peterchen though, will have to take a look at this in more detail - keen to follow best practice wherever possible.