# Using Clone() to duplicate an ASP.NET MVC / EntityFramework model object

Tags: c#

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443384/why-use-clone) about using `Clone()` and want to know if what I'm after will be achieved.  My understanding from reading that question is that `Clone()` does a shallow copy, however reading elsewhere led me to believe differently, and now I'm confused.

Our project has a class `Rule` that has an `ICollection<ICondition> Conditions`.  We'd like to provide users with a shortcut method to duplicate an existing `Condition` and modify it rather than start from scratch.  To that end, we're providing a **`Copy To New`** button.

`ICondition` looks like this:

```
interface ICondition
{
    long ID { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    string IfStatement { get; set; }
    string PriceVersion { get; set; }
    PriceDetail Pricing { get; set; }
    bool StandardOption { get; set; }
}
```

Given what I've read about `Clone()`, I'm fairly confident it would work the way I expect by using `ICondition newCondition = conditionToCopy.Clone()`, though I'm unsure if `Pricing` would be duplicated correctly, since it's a complex data type.

So, the first part of my question is, "will this work?"  I would just try it and see, however `ICondition` (or really its underlying `Condition`) doesn't seem to provide a method for `Clone()`, which leads me to the second part of my question: can I leverage `IClonable` to enable this functionality?  If so, where?

Is this the way?

```
public static class Condition : IClonable
{
    ...
    public Condition Clone(Condition conditionToClone)
    {
        return new Condition 
        { 
            Description = this.Description,
            EffectiveDate = this.EffectiveDate,
            IfStatement = this.IfStatement,
            PriceVersion = this.PriceVersion,
            Pricing = this.Pricing,
            StandardOption = this.StandardOption
        }
    }
}
```

And, given that as the answer, is there any utility to declaring `IClonable` as the interface?  Does it add any value?

**Update:**

Based on the below answer, I decided to do this, which at least builds (and hopefully runs; haven't tried it yet):

```
public class Condition
{
    ...
    public Condition Clone()
    {
        return (Condition)base.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

I still don't see the need for `ICloneable`, so have left it out. The compiler was complaining about it anyway, something about the base class not being `object`.

Comment: Your way will work fine.

Comment: More reading, and I think what I was hoping for was something like `System.Object.MemberwiseClone` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), though try as I might, I can't seem to get IntelliSense to offer that as an option.  :\

Comment: I too had in the past been confused on deep clones, clones etc.  I almost never do it; rather, I use the pattern you show above almost all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things. First Condition class should not be static. Second, PriceDetail class [Property pricing], Also need to impleemnt ICloneable. Instance class will allow `base.MemberWiseClone()` method.

```
public class Condition : ICloneable
{

    public object Clone()
    {
        base.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Comment: But what's the usefulness of `ICloneable`?

Comment: It is basically for instructing compiler to copy "value" of properties than "reference" as it happens while copying Reference type variable. Creating new instance of a same class and passing same values will do the same thing, but this is more clean.

Comment: From reading MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ICloneable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true), as far as I can tell, `ICloneable` simply requires that you implement a method `Clone()` and does nothing else.

Comment: Also, should that be `{ return base.MemberwiseClone(); }` ??

Comment: Yes we should return.