# Basic Windows 10 Powershell question on variable initializaton and passing arguments

Tags: windows, powershell

I am currently learning about Powershell and how to write a script to launch an application. The following snippet of code I borrowed and have modified to learn how to launch notepad. The question I have is what does `$args.Clone()` do or derive from? (It is from the original code which had a different path and executable program being defined/called.)  I realize that the variable $myArgs is being initialized to the left of the equal sign by the function on the right. However, I have not been successful finding resources about what can you can do with `.Clone()` so I thought I would try and ask here.

BTW, the script works as it launchs notepad.exe and names the text file 'pp'. If the file has not previously been created, it asks me if I want to name the text file 'pp'.

```
$exePath = $env:NOTEPAD_HOME + '/Windows/notepad.exe'
$myArgs = $args.Clone()
$myArgs += '-pp'
$myArgs += $env:NOTEPAD_HOME
& $exePath $myArgs
```

Comment: `.Clone()` does exactly what you'd expect from cloning. It makes a duplicate copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use Clone()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443384/why-use-clone)  (That's a C# question, but that and PowerShell both being languages to interface with .NET make the answer the same.)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Your modification of `$myArgs` can be simplified as follows:

```
$myArgs = $args + '-pp' + $env:NOTEPAD_HOME
```

With an *array* as the LHS, operator `+` performs *concatenation*, i.e., it *appends* to the array, though note that appending means that a *new* array is created in the process, given that arrays are fixed-size data structures in .NET.

The fact that a *new* array is implicitly created anyway makes the call to `.Clone()` in your code unnecessary.

---

#### Background Information

Typically - and in the case of the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) - the `.Clone()` method is an implementation of the [`System.ICloneable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ICloneable) *interface*.

The purpose of `.Clone()` is to create a *copy* (clone) of an object, but - as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443402/45375) linked to by [BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon) explains - the *semantics* of this operation - *shallow* (see below) vs. *deep* copying - aren't prescribed, which is why use of `System.ICloneable` is generally *discouraged*.

**`$args` is an *array* ([`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array)), and for arrays, [`.Clone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone) creates a so-called *shallow* copy.** That is, how the elements of the array are copied depends on whether they are instances of *value types* or *reference* types:

- for *value-type* elements, the new array will have an *independent copy* of the data of the original array's elements.
- for *reference-type* elements, the new array will have a copy of the *reference*  of the original array's elements, which means that elements of both arrays point to *same data* (objects).

For more information about value types vs. reference types, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60102611/45375).

**PowerShell *implicitly* clones arrays in the way described when you use `+=` and `+`**.