# Clone object without changing the values of the original object C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make a copy of a MyGame class and use it in my simulation for game trials before I select a move to play.

For example :

```
public class MyGame
  {
     private int Start;
     private Board board;

     //Constructor 

     public void Play()
     {
         //play game 
     }

     public object Clone()
     {     


     }

  }

 public class Board
    {
        private int Count; 

        //Constructor

        //Some methods and properties

     public object Clone()
     {     

     }

    }
```

Writing code for the method Clone() I have tried

1. MemberwiseClone()
2. (Board) this.MemberwiseClone()
3. Board b = (Board) this.Board

I have read alot of articles and forums about this topic. The answer most people
use is Deep cloning objects in C#, I tried samples with respect to my project but I still 
get my simulation modifying the original object (MyGame Class) and not the copy.

Comment: I think you are messing up with the reference to the new object (if your cloning is successful).

Comment: Memberwise clone doesn't work if members are **reference types** (it'll clone pointers, not pointed objects). Each object must support cloning. A dirty way (for serializable objects) can be to **serialize root object in memory** (and then deserialize the cloned one).

Comment: How do you call  Clone() and how/when the modifying code?

Comment: Oh okay sorry i forgot, each class implement the ICloneable interface.

Comment: Is it no option to just create a new Object and set its prperties to the same values as in the original object ?

Comment: MyGame playoutMC = (MyGame) currentGame.Clone();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I have an example for a deep copy, which deeply copies all *reference type objects* that are used with a **copy constructor**:

```
public sealed class MyGame
{
    private int start;
    private Board board;

    public MyGame(MyGame orig)
    {
        // value types - like integers - can easily be
        // reused
        this.start = orig.start;

        // reference types must be clones seperately, you
        // must not use orig.board directly here
        this.board = new Board(orig.board);
    }
}

public sealed class Board
{
    private int count;

    public Board(Board orig)
    {
        // here we have a value type again
        this.count = orig.count;

        // here we have no reference types. if we did
        // we'd have to clone them too, as above
    }
}
```

I think your copy might be somehow *shallow* and re-use some references (like for instance `this.board = orig.board` instead of creating a *new* board). This is a guess though, as I can't see your cloning implementation.

Furthermore, I used *copy constructors* instead of implementing `ICloneable`. The implementation is almost the same. One advantage though is that you simplify dealing with *subclasses*:

Suppose you had a `MyAwesomeGame : MyGame`, *not overriding* `MyGame.Clone`. What would you get from `myAwesomeGame.Clone()`? Actually, still a new `MyGame` because `MyGame.Clone` is the method in charge. One may carelessly expect a properly cloned `MyAwesomeGame` here, however. `new MyGame(myAwesomeGame)` still copies somehow incompletely, but it's more obvious. In my example I made the classes `sealed` to avoid this failures. If you can seal them, there's good change it will make your life simpler.

Implementing `ICloneable` is not recommended in general, see [Why should I implement ICloneable in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c) for more detailed and general information.

Here I have **an `ICloneable` approach** anyway, to make things complete and enable you to compare and contrast:

```
public class MyGame : ICloneable
{
    private int start;
    private Board board;

    public object Clone()
    {
        var copy = new MyGame();
        copy.start = this.start;
        copy.board = (Board)this.board.Clone();
        return copy;
    }
}

public class Board : ICloneable
{
    private int count;

    public object Clone()
    {
        var copy = new Board();
        copy.count = this.count;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good read. So now i am confused .... as to which approach. I am going implement both, which ever works for me I will work with that. Thanks.

Comment: @CrateDuke I apologise for confusing you. The implementation is very similar with `ICloneable`, and both approaches will work. Good luck with the implementation and don't hesitate ask when you need further help.

Comment: IClonable is the Microsoft sanctioned method. Copy constructor is most discoverable. There is no reason that the Clone method cannot call the copy constructor. Then you get both patterns for free!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most reliable way to implement deep cloning is to serialize, and then deserialize your objects. This can have a large performance cost associated with it. Consider classes from this namespace for serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.aspx

Deep cloning requires recursively creating a new instance of *every* property that is not a value type. Cloning `MyGame` would require a new instance of `MyGame` and a new instance of `Board`, both populated with the same `Start` and `Count` values as their originals. This is fiddly and a nightmare to maintain. As you can guess, it is not an automatic process out of the box but it can be, using reflection (which is how the xml serialization above works.

`MemberwiseClone` only creates a new instance of the object you called it on - all references remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

`MemberwiseClone()` creates a <strike>stupid</strike> shallow clone of each member of an object. This works fine when members are value types but in case of reference types it fails because it'll clone pointers and not pointed objects.

Starting from your code a memberwise clone is something like this:

```
public object Clone()
{
    MyGame cloned = new MyGame();
    cloned.Start = this.Start; // Copied (cloned) because value type
    cloned.Board = this.Board; // This is not a copy, just a reference!
}
```

A better solution for a deep clone would be to implement `ICloneable` (for example, otherwise a *copy constructor* approach is also good) for each reference type, let's suppose `Board` is cloneable too:

```
public object Clone()
{
    MyGame cloned = new MyGame();
    cloned.Start = this.Start;
    cloned.Board = (Board)this.Board.Clone();
}
```

Please note that in your example `Board` can implement `Clone()` using `MemberwiseClone()` because its members are all value types.

If you can't manage this (for example because code is not accesible) or you need a quick/dirty solution you may consider to user serializaiton (in memory). Which serializer is a big question, each one has some limitations (about what's serialized and how). For example XML serializer won't serialize private fields (it won't serialize fields at all). Faster one is binary formatter but you need to mark each class with a proper attribute.

Change according serializer you prefer (according to your requirements), in this case I assume you marked `MyGame` and `Board` as `[Serializable]` for the quick binary serialization:

```
public object Clone()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think *stupid copy* might be a *shallow copy* if I understand correctly. Is this correct, and maybe worth an edit?

Comment: @Adriano this means any object within any of this classes must also be [Serializable] ?

Comment: @CrateDuke yes. It's the price to pay to use a serializer (each one has its own limitations, sometimes not so obvious). That's why it's a quick/dirty solution, IMO best approach is an **explicit ICloneable** implementation (or a copy constructor even if it's little bit more prolix and you won't **benefit of MemberwiseClone** when applicable).

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of the serialization implementation. One problem with `ICloneable` is that it does not specify how deep or shallow a copy is: *It does not specify whether the cloning operation performs a deep copy, a shallow copy, or something in between.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx

Comment: @MatthiasMeid I agree, in literature everyone suggests to use something else (custom interface but with well defined behavior). ICloneable were intended to be a deep clone (for members where it's applicable) but it has not been documented enough (or people didn't understand the difference at that time) so now it's discouraged (and even inside Framework there are exceptions to this rule, blame!). I still use it (when I need it) because I feel it's more confusing to introduce a new interface when exactly the same is available (I just document it's a deep clone) but...it's just my opinion.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid from the ref: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) I want to believe this sentence says it all "Because callers of Clone cannot depend on the method performing a predictable cloning operation, we recommend that ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs."

Comment: In the end a copy constructor was what i used to solve my problem and all seems to be working perfectly. Thanks @MatthiasMeid

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public static T DeepCopy<T>(this T obj)
        {
            T result;
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {

                serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
                ms.Position = 0;

                result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
                ms.Close();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Just code for copy and pasting without any explanation won't be helpful to future visitors with similar problems, nor is it really helpful to the OP if he or she wants to *understand* what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have two extension methods that I use to achieve this. Demo code below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SimpleCloneDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", Surname = "Doe" };

            var clone = person.Clone();
            clone.Id = 5;
            clone.FirstName = "Jane";

            Console.WriteLine(@"person: {0}", person);
            Console.WriteLine(@"clone: {0}", clone);

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Id: {0}, Full Name: {1}, {2}", Id, Surname, FirstName);
        }
    }

    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static T Clone<T>(this T entity) where T : class
        {
            var clone = Activator.CreateInstance(entity.GetType());
            var entityPropValueDictionary = entity.AsPropValueDictionary();
            foreach (var prop in clone.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                clone.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(clone, entityPropValueDictionary[prop.Name]);
            }
            return clone as T;
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, object> AsPropValueDictionary<T>(this T instance, params BindingFlags[] bindingFlags)
        {
            var runtimeBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Default;

            switch (bindingFlags.Count())
            {
                case 0:
                    runtimeBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Default;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    runtimeBindingFlags = bindingFlags[0];
                    break;
                default:
                    runtimeBindingFlags = bindingFlags.Aggregate(runtimeBindingFlags, (current, bindingFlag) => current | bindingFlag);
                    break;
            }

            return runtimeBindingFlags == BindingFlags.Default
                ? instance.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(instance))
                : instance.GetType().GetProperties(runtimeBindingFlags).ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(instance));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: SimpleCloneDemo Result Screenshot]

I wrote these quick-and-dirty extension methods in a hurry so there are probably some issues with it and they are probably horribly inefficient, but they seemed to work for my use case. They may help you, too.

Comment: Will this make deep copies of any properties that are reference types?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I tried this code...but incase you have a sub class within the main class then you will still have issues. The best so  far, which has worked for me is a Copy Constructor.

Comment: @CrateDuke yes I noticed that ... unfortunately my code only works for the simplest case, and I cannot see how `Activator.CreateInstance` could be generalized to determine which constructor to use to create a clone of the passed-in instance, without some heavy-duty reflection. The copy constructor is actually a deceptively simple solution - I like it!