# Is there anything wrong with this IClonable implementation

Tags: c#

I haven't programmed in C# but my son asked me if there is anything wrong with this implementation

```
public class Person : A, IClonable {
....

    public object Clone() {
       return this;
    }
}
```

My gut feeling is that it is wrong because this Clone() method implementation does not return any new object. I think that the Clone() method should create a new object or call a method that creates a new object and then return it. That is what I said to my son, but not having done any C# programming I became uncertain. Could someone shed a bit light on this.

Comment: You're right: the method should create a new object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My gut feeling is that it is wrong because this Clone() method
>   implementation does not return any new object

That feeling does not deceive you. You need to create a new object if you want to create a copy of it. Otherwise it's just the same reference and this implemenntation is pointless and misleading.

Consider that your class has a `StringProperty`:

```
Person p1 = new Person{ StringProperty = "Foo" };
Person p2 = (Person)p1.Clone();
p2.StringProperty = "Bah";
Console.Write(p1.StringProperty); // "Bah"
```

You see that even if i change the property on `p2` i also modify `StringProperty` of the other instance since it's actually the same.

So you need something like this:

```
public object Clone() {
    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.StringProperty = this.StringProperty;
    // ...
    return p2;
}
```

Although i prefer to create a different method  `Copy` instead since it's often not clear what `Clone` does.  Even Microsoft recommends against implementing `ICloneable`.

[Why should I implement ICloneable in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces are contracts. If your class implements ICloneable, it [promises to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Supports cloning, which creates a **new instance** of a class with the same value as an existing instance.

Now if the writer of `Clone() { return this; }`, or anyone else using this code, relies on the return value to *be a clone of the original*, and makes some modifications that may not have been made on the original object, you have a bug to track down.

Answer (score 2):

Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and check [this examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/clone)

I think you are right - you dont create new object , so if one want to clone and change the object - he will change the original object , which is not what expected

Comment: That is not a reference to IClonable

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [IClonable documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does NOT speficy a deep or shallow copy.

It just specifies that it should copy. And this implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

To clone object try this.

**Method 1:**

```
public class Person : ICloneable
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Address PersonAddress { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        Person newPerson = (Person)this.MemberwiseClone();
        newPerson.PersonAddress = (Address)this.PersonAddress.Clone();

        return newPerson;
    }
}

public class Address : ICloneable
{
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
public class Person : ICloneable
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Address PersonAddress { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        object objResult = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, this);

            ms.Position = 0;
            objResult = bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
        return objResult;
    }
}
```

**Method 3 :**

```
public class Person : ICloneable
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public Address PersonAddress { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            var objResult = new Person();
            objResult.LastName = this.LastName;
            objResult.FirstName = this.FirstName;
            objResult.PersonAddress = new Address();
            objResult.PersonAddress.HouseNumber = this.PersonAddress.HouseNumber;
            objResult.PersonAddress.StreetName = this.PersonAddress.StreetName;

            return objResult;
        }
    }
```