# 'The type or namespace name 'ICloneable' could not be found' in win store app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I am developing windows store app and getting error of *'The type or namespace name 'ICloneable' could not be found'*.

Here is my code.

```
public class DiscoveryItem : ICloneable
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    private string _node = string.Empty;
    private JabberID _JID;

    public DiscoveryItem()
    {
    }

public DiscoveryItem(JabberID JID, string name, string node)
{
    _JID = JID;
    _name = name;
    _node = node;
}

public object Clone()
{
    return new DiscoveryItem(_JID, _name, _node);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c and http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2012/03/30/no-icloneable-in-winrt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows store apps are using their own version of the .net framework.

There is no `ICloneable` for windows store apps, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx).

The recommendation of Microsoft what to use instead is:

> A custom method that returns the appropriate type