# Copy constructor in polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#

Please first take a look at this simple code;

This is my base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
    }

    public BaseClass(BaseClass b)
    {
    }

    public virtual string GetMSG()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
}
```

and this is the derived one:

```
public class DrivenClass : BaseClass
{
    public string MSG { get; set; }

    public DrivenClass(string msg)
    {
        MSG = msg;
    }

    public DrivenClass(DrivenClass d)
    {
        MSG = d.MSG;
    }

    public override string GetMSG()
    {
        return  MSG;
    }
}
```

and this is the test:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public BaseClass B { get; set; }
    public DrivenClass D { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        D = new DrivenClass("Driven");
        B = new BaseClass(D);
        MessageBox.Show("B:" + B.GetMSG() + "\nD:" + D.GetMSG());
    }
}
```

Now my question is what should I do that `B = new BaseClass(D);` works like `B = new DrivenClass(D);` ?

I'm using this in polymorphism and I like to use one copy-constructor instead of different driven ones.

I want the output like this :

```
Driven
Driven
```

but now it's like this :

```
Base
Driven
```

Comment: I'm missing what the actual desired behavior is, or what the actual use case is that calls for it.  BaseClass.GetMSG is implemented as returning a hardcoded string, "Base".  An instance of BaseClass that is not an instance of any derived class will only ever print "Base".

Comment: yes @JoeAmenta , I know, I desire to assign every Item of a list from driven classes of base to one object of base by copy constructor and I can't do this. actually the base class' function should never be called in case that I didn't call base.GetMsg() in the overridden function.

Comment: What unique, instance-specific behavior does an object of type BaseClass have by itself?  If this is a simplified reproduction of your actual use case, I think that it's simplified a bit too much.  If you have a list of objects of type BaseClass (or one of its derived classes), and you want to create copies of those instances using a BaseClass constructor that accepts a BaseClass instance as input, then all you can rely on is the instance members as defined in BaseClass, of which there are none here.

Comment: Store 'MSG' in 'BaseClass'. Otherwise it can never know about the text. Initializing it with an object that does know the text means nothing as that text is not stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an overridden virtual Copy method instead of a copy constructor.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
    }

    public virtual BaseClass ShallowCopy()
    {
        return new BaseClass();
    }

    public virtual string GetMSG()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
}

public class DrivenClass : BaseClass
{
    public string MSG { get; set; }

    public DrivenClass(string msg)
    {
        MSG = msg;
    }

    public override BaseClass ShallowCopy() {
        return new DrivenClass(this.MSG);
    }

    public override string GetMSG()
    {
        return  MSG;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
D = new DrivenClass("Driven");
B = D.ShallowCopy();
```

This will work because calling a virtual method always calls the actual overriden implementation in the subclass, even when called from the baseclass interface.

Comment: how about using clone?

Comment: You mean the `ICloneable` interface? [Apparently not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c#699221), because it does not indicate whether your copy is a deep or shallow one. You can simply write your own generic interface though.

Comment: I agree with what the other comments, though: Reflect on your design first and think about what you really want to achieve before you implement this. You might be on the wrong track by trying to copy in the first place.

Comment: This method starts to get pretty hairy as you start to get longer and longer inheritance chains.  How do you make sure that you faithfully reproduce the base class's behavior in the derived class's version?  One possibility might look something like `protected virtual void InitializeFrom(BaseClass b)` that derived classes might override to set their own values after the base sets its values, but I'm not sure what the end goal actually is to make that an actual proposition.

Comment: Per my previous comment, `protected` because want it to only be called from the copy method to guarantee that we can cast the `BaseClass` instance to `DrivenClass` if it's called from `DrivenClass`'s overridden `ShallowCopy` method.

Comment: I agree this is most likely not the road the op should take, but without knowing what he _actually_ wants to achieve this is the easiest way to produce the desired output from the limited information he has given. I still think he might be asking the wrong question. Future visitors should be wary of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is normal because you create new instance of base class here. Therefore you never override the GetMSG method:

```
B = new BaseClass(D);
```

What you wanted to do is to have the same public class:

```
public BaseClass B { get; set; }
```

and to give it the value of new DrivenClass(D)

```
B = new DrivenClass(D);
```