# How to make a deep copy of a List of Object

Tags: c#, list, object, copy, deep-copy

Hi I have  a list of objects(list1) and I'd like to make a copy of this list but I want that the objects in the second list(list2) to  not be linked to the one in first list.

this is what I do

```
    list<Obj> list1 = new list<Obj>{};
    // I fill the list1 with objects Obj
    // now I want to make a deep copy this is what I do

   list<Obj>  list2 = new list<Obj>(list1);
   // but when I edit an object in list 1 I also edit the object in list2
```

I'd like to be able to edit the objects in list1 without  edititng the object in list2,how can I get that???

thanks for your answers

Comment: Look at the [ICloneable interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Assuming your Obj isn't a value type you will have to loop through your 'list1' and clone each individual object (and add that to list2).

Comment: If you don't want to implement ICloneable, you can use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/891715

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the [`ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in your `Obj` class. After that, you can call this code to create your second list:

```
list<Obj>  list2 = new list<Obj>(list1.Select(x => x?.Clone()));
```

It will clone every item in the list. (With null-check)

Comment: Don't implement `ICloneable`, make your own interface and use that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c

Comment: Well, the concept still holds.

Comment: Indeed, the solution is good, I like it. I just think that ICloneable is a pretty poor interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a **copy constructor** to your `Obj`.

Then loop through list1 create a new instance of your objects using the copy constructor and add it to list2.

**Example:**

Copy constructor:

```
public Obj(Obj copyFrom)
{
   this.field1 = copyFrom.field1;
   .
   .
}
```

With the following LINQ query you have a one liner to use the above contructor:

```
list2.AddRange(list1.Select(s => new Obj(s)));
```